# Is there a plugin in IntelliJ IDEA CE for SSH client?

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, plugins

I am using Windows 11. Usually, I connect to my EC2 server through SSH using MobaXterm (Third-party desktop application) to perform some operations on it. I would like to know if there is a plugin in IntelliJ IDEA which would allow me connect to the server within my IDE. Anything like an SSH client would work for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is in Ultimate version.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-ssh-terminal.html